# Using multiple forms to insert data to DB using Jquery & PHP without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery

I have working code for posting data to DB using PHP and Jquery without refreshing the page.

But however, I could only use 1 form with the given code, if I'm to add another form with different variables both the forms getting submitted.

My code goes as:

**index:**

*Query starts*

```
$countlikes = 1;
$countdislikes = 1;

<form data-id='<?= $countlikes?>' action="likeinsert" method="post" id="myform<?= $countlikes?>">
      <input type="hidden" id="fid<?= $countlikes?>" name="fid" value="<?php echo $f_id; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" id="uid<?= $countlikes?>" name="uid" value="<?php echo $u_id; ?>" />
      <button style="border:none; background:transparent;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Like" class="up"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i><?= $f_likes; ?></button>
</form>

<form data-id='<?= $countdislikes?>' action="dislikeinsert" method="post" id="myform<?= $countdislikes?>">
      <input type="hidden" id="fid<?= $countdislikes?>" name="fid" value="<?php echo $f_id; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" id="uid<?= $countdislikes?>" name="uid" value="<?php echo $u_id; ?>" />
      <button style="border:none; background:transparent;" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="DisLike" class="down"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i><?= $f_dislikes; ?></button>
</form>

$countlikes ++;
$countdislikes ++;
```

*Query Ends*

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script>
        $(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let id = $(this).data('id'); 
            $.post(
                'likeinsert.php',
                {
                    fid: $("#fid"+id).val(),
                    uid: $("#uid"+id).val()
                },
                function(result){
                    if(result == "success"){
                        $("#result").val("Values Inserted");
                    } else {
                        $("#result").val("Error");
                    }
                }
           );
        });
    </script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let id = $(this).data('id'); 
            $.post(
                'dislikeinsert.php',
                {
                    fiid: $("#fid"+id).val(),
                    uiid: $("#uid"+id).val()
                },
                function(result){
                    if(result == "success"){
                        $("#result").val("Values Inserted");
                    } else {
                        $("#result").val("Error");
                    }
                }
           );
        });
    </script>
```

When I to click on any form button, both forms are getting submitted.

Comment: Do you want to prevent one of them from submitting? You need to limit the event to be called only when a specific form is submitted. At the moment both of them are triggered wherever any form is submitted `.on('submit','form'`

Comment: @Dharman So, how can i specifically mention particular form to be submitted..?

Comment: Give your forms a better id. Then you can use `'form#myID'` and the id will be different for each form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening, because you are adding two `submit` event listeners on both forms, so when you submit one form, both jquery scripts are getting executed.

To prevent this, add form's unique ids to your event listeners (in your case they are myform1 and myform1, but you should make them unique), somewhat like this:

```js
$(document).on('submit','form#dislikesForm',function(e){
    request to dislikeinsert.php ...

$(document).on('submit','form#likesForm',function(e){
    request to likeinsert.php...
```

Comment: So if i m to change `<form data-id='<?= $countlikes?>' action="likeinsert" method="post" id="myformlike<?= $countlikes?>">` and the other form to `<form data-id='<?= $countdislikes?>' action="likeinsert" method="post" id="myformdislike<?= $countdislikes?>">` , Here I have $countlikes and $countdislikes adding +1 for each like or dislike button through out the query. For this scenario, how can I mention the form id in the Jquery code . i.e., `$(document).on('submit','form#myformlike',function(e){`

Comment: Do you really need to add these numbers to forms id? I would leave the form ids static
`<form data-id='<?= $countdislikes?>' action="likeinsert" method="post" id="myformdislike>` - without this $countdislikes variable. But if it's neccessary for you, you must also add this number to the selector in your jquery script -
`$(document).on('submit','form#myformlike<?= $countdislikes; ?>',function(e){`
It is not a good practice though, to mix Javascript and PHP.

But overall - the form id and selector in script must be equal